# Frequencies in unordered cartesian products

Tags: combinatorics, products

This is a novice question. If I have an unordered cartesian product of some list with a repeat sequence, how can I calculate the frequency with which a member of that list occurs in the combinations?

For example given the list:

```
list = {1,2,3,4}
```

The unordered cartesian product with a repeat length of 3 should give:

```
(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3)........(4,4,4)
```

How can I calculate the number of times 1 appears at least once in this set? If I change this to at least twice can this be done? I was looking around for a formula but could not find one. Thanks

Comment: Count the number of times there are _no_ ones, and subtract that from the total number of triples.

Comment: Sorry what do mean by counting? If you mean looping through the set and counting  then that works for small repeat lengths. If for example we have a repeat length of 9 then we get set with 262144 members. Do you know how to mathematically calculate this? Thanks

Comment: x @user3063482: By "count" in this context I mean neither more nor less than "calculate the number of".

Comment: Do you mean the number of 1's appearing, or the number of tuples ?

Comment: Hi Roddy MacPhee. I mean the number of members of the set that have at-least one 1 in it. So (1,1,1) would be part of this subset as well as (4,4,1) etc